# Fit multiple models with the Caret R Package (regression training)

Tags: r, machine-learning, r-caret

I want to fit multiple models to the same dataset using the Caret R Package.

My outcome is quantitative continuous, and my predictors are qualitative binary (absent vs. present). Each row corresponds to an individual.

I run automatic feature selection methods, then shuffled the predictors from the training data set. The next step would be to fit multiple models to the same dataset. But what models (methodList) would typically fit my data?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the model info, and specifically if their $type has "Regression"

That should be a good start at least. If you have purrr, something like this, for simplicity, equivalent `sapply` call if not:

```
mi <- getModelInfo()
ms %>% purrr::map_lgl( ~ "Regression" %in% .x$type )
```